# xCode/iOS Search on multiple criteria

Tags: xcode, search, ios4, criteria

I have an iPhone project that has a word and its translation.

I can search using either one or the other, using something like:

tableModel.searchPropertyName = @"word";  or

tableModel.searchPropertyName = @"translation";

I'd like to be able to search based on either.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html), construct an "and" predicate or "or" predicate that contains both of your searches as subpredicates.

If you're not using NSPredicate, switch to using NSPredicate then follow the first sentence.